# Extrair dados do SAP através do Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, erp

Olá!


Estou tentando integrar o Excel com o SAP via VBA. Gostaria de rodar a transação "MB51" com alguns parâmetros como data, depósito e movimento e trazer os dados obtidos para a planilha do Excel via VBA.

Tenho tentado realizar esta tarefa com base no seguinte código:

```
Sub SAP()

Dim sap As Object
Dim conn As Object

Set sap = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
Set conn = sap.Connection
conn.System = "S0P"
conn.Client = ""
conn.User = ""
conn.Password = ""
conn.Language = "PT"

If conn.logon(0, False) <> True Then
    MsgBox "Logon to the SAP system is not possible", vbOKOnly, "Comment"
End If


Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")          'Utiliza o objeto da interface gráfica do SAP
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine    'Conecta ao SAP que está rodando no momento
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)               'Encontra o primeiro sistema que está conectado
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)              'Encontra a primeira sessão (janela) dessa conexão

If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize    

Dim objExcel
Dim objSheet, intRow, aux, Log
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

DataInicial = Range("H2") 
DataFinal = Range("H3")

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NMB51"

End Sub
```

Adicionei a referência "SAP GUI Scripiting API" no Excel mas sempre que o código chega na linha:

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
```

Recebo a mensagem de erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar ou indicar o caminho?

Answer (score 3):

Tente excluir essa linha,

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")          'Utiliza o objeto da interface gráfica do SAP
```

```
Sub testar()

Dim objExcel
Dim objSheet, intRow, aux, Log
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    If Not IsObject(Applicationa) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set Applicationa = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If

    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = Applicationa.Children(0)
    End If

    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If

    If IsObject(WScript) Then

       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"

    End If

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize    



DataInicial = Range("H2") 
DataFinal = Range("H3")

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NMB51"

End Sub
```

Também e necessário ativar a opção **SAP GUI Configuration**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Faça a conexão do Excel - SAP através do gravador de script. Deppois de gravar todo o script, é só substituir as quatorze linhas iniciais pela linha

Set session = GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine.Children(0).Children(0)

Isso conecta o Excel ao SAP